# Windows Azure Run Once Routine

Tags: windows, azure

I'm trying to initialize my data in my Azure Data Tables but I only want this to happen once on the server at startup (i.e. via the WebRole Role Entry OnStart routine).  The problem is if I have multiple instances starting up at the same time then potentially either one of those instances can add records to the same table at the same time hence duplicating the data at runtime.

Is there there like an overarching routine for all instances?  An application object in which I can shove a value into and check it in each of the instances to see if the tables have been created or not?  A singleton of some sort that azure exposes?

Cheers
Rob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but you could use a Blob [lease](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/managing-concurrency-in-windows-azure-with-leases) as a mutex.  You could also use a table lock in SQL Azure, if you're using that.

Comment: Thanks Oliver.  In the end I went with creating an Azure Table Store  called StartUp with one variable "CreatedTables" set to false.  I have a thread.sleep call that I pass in a random number between 1 and 30 seconds and set the table variable to true first time through.  It works a treat and prevents other instances initializing the tables etc

Comment: @PazoozaTestPazman: are you sure you won't have a race condition there?  E.g. two role instances simultaneously read CreatedTables and find it false, and both think they're doing the initialisation?

Comment: As Oliver said, there's a risk of a race condition. So you may want to combine the table with a blob lease to do locking. Then you only need to deal with the reset of the value if you redeploy and it neds to be re-run.

Comment: okay thanks for pointing that out I'll change it to include blob lease

Comment: Just a note for others, Steve Marx blob lease solution is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a Queue, and drop a message in there and then just one role would pick up the message and process it.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new single instance role that does this job on role start.

Answer (score 0):

To be really paranoid about this and address the event of failure in the middle of writing the data, you can do something even more complex.

A queue message is a great way to ensure transactional capabilities as long as the work you are doing can be idempotent.

- Each instance adds a message to a queue.
- Each instance polls  the queue and on receiving a message

  - Reads the locking row from the table.

    - If the ‘create data state’ value is ‘unclaimed’

      - Attempts to update the row with a ‘in process’ value and a timeout expiration timestamp based on the amount of time needed to create the data.
      - if the update is successful, the instance owns the task of creating the data

        - So create the data
        - update the ‘create data state’ to ‘committed’
        - delete the message
      - else if the update is unsuccessful the instance does not own the task

        - so just delete the message.
    - Else if the ‘create data’ value is ‘in process’, check if the current time is past the expiration timestamp.

      - That would imply that the ‘in process’ failed
      - So try all over again to set the state to ‘in process’, delete the incomplete written rows
      - And try recreating the data, updating the state and deleting the message
    - Else if the ‘create data’ value is ‘committed’

      - Just delete the queue message, since the work has been done